# How to Submit multiple dynamic forms with the same input field name in angular?

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I am new with angular ionic. I want to submit one form at one time with validation. On the page their is multiple form with the same input field name.

I have tried with Jquery it working may be i have experience with JQuery. But in angular 7 i just started.

`````
    <ion-card *ngFor="let result of searchData.data">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <form (ngSubmit)="updateStock(result.id)" >
            <ion-item lines="none">
              <ion-thumbnail>
                <img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y">
              </ion-thumbnail>
              <ion-item lines="none">
                <p>{{result.title}}</p>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-row>
              <ion-col size="6" size-sm>
                <ion-item>
                  <ion-label position="floating">Add Quantity</ion-label>
                  <ion-input type="number" name="quantity" maxlength="5" [(ngModel)]="stock.quantity"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <div class="ion-text-end">Available: {{result.quantity}}</div>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col size="6" size-sm> 
                <ion-item>
                  <ion-label position="floating">Product Condition</ion-label>
                  <ion-select placeholder="Select One" name="product_status_id" [(ngModel)]="stock.product_status_id">
                    <ion-select-option value="1">New</ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value="2">Old</ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value="3">Return</ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value="4">Other</ion-select-option>
                  </ion-select>
                </ion-item>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <p>If Return then ask from witch platform it comes</p>
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label  position="floating">Return from</ion-label>
                <ion-select placeholder="Select One" name="marketplace_id" [(ngModel)]="stock.marketplace_id">
                  <ion-select-option value="1">Amazon</ion-select-option>
                  <ion-select-option value="2">Paytm</ion-select-option>
                  <ion-select-option value="3">Flipkart</ion-select-option>
                  <ion-select-option value="4">Shop</ion-select-option>
                  <ion-select-option value="5">Other</ion-select-option>
                </ion-select>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <ion-button color="success" type="submit" block>Update</ion-button>
            <ion-button color="danger" type="button" block>Edit</ion-button>
          </form>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
  <ng-template #noData>
    <div class="ion-text-center">
      {{noDataFound}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>````
`````

Answer (score 0):

You should look into FormBuilder which is a part of Angular.

It is the standard solution for scenarios like this.

The high level concept is that instead of building the forms structure on the page, you build a model of the form using the FormBuilder api.

You can then get at the data all through the code and decide what you want to submit in each case.

What you are building at the moment is a template driven form. This alternative is known as a reactive form.

A great starting point for this is on Alligator.io:

- https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-introduction/

Side note: It took me a few goes to get my head around this but once I figured it out it has become a powerful way to process complex form data in Angular / Ionic so I recommend you stick with it even if you get a bit confused to start off with.

Comment: Thank you . But i have more than 3 form on the same page. Each form field have the same name eg. "quantity" . When i am submitting the form it through some error. Using model is good suggestion. But as per users interaction its not the friendly way. I found the alternate way for that is to use the Local variable reference. that is #quantity or else and pass it to the function. it resolve my problem for now. But i am still searching for stranded way to submit the multiple forms

Comment: That's why I said keep at it as it's confusing :) You need to forget about jquery ways of working, they are not relevant in Angular. You are using html but you are building a web app not a site. In most cases you should consider directly touching the html through references as a kind of "failure" as the entire thing should be done using models and code. A reactive form supports nested forms and dynamic forms which change at runtime. Dig into it and you will see.

Comment: thank you. Yes, confusion help me to explore. Yes i am not using jquery now.Pure code in angular only.. Thank you